# Manipulate an array using javascript and displaying it via Handlebars

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, handlebars.js

I'd like to work on a data array containing only strings, which can be manipulated using js/jq easily (like adding/modifying string values) and displayed via handlebars.
This array can be of any format either js array or JSON data (whichever works with handlebars best)
What type of array should i use, and how should i achieve it?
Thanks

My data will be in this form:

```
"flightno": "F10001",
"origin": "Sydney",
"destination": "Delhi"
```

so for example: the flightno changes depending on what the user selects through the html form, then this flightno is displayed on the html page through handlebars expression.

Comment: So you want to take an array of "any format", do non-specific "manipulation", and then display the data in a format that you don't show? And the data that you do show is not in a valid JS or JSON format. Please [edit] your question to make it [less vague](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sorry, i thought showing what my data is will explain everything, i hope its clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple JSON. On change of origin or destination set the json data and compile a handlebar template. Then append the html to the element.

Say your json looks like this

```
var data = {
  "flightno": "F10001",
  "origin": "Sydney",
  "destination": "Delhi"
};
```

Say your DOM looks like this

```
<div>
  <select name="origin" id="origin">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
  <select name="destination" id="destination">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
  <div class="flightno"></div>
</div>
```

Your handlebars template for flightno will be

```
template = Handlebars.compile('<div class="someclass">{{flightno}}</div>');
$('#flightno').html(template(data));
```

Comment: i was using this approach but it wasn't working, could you please elaborate what was wrong, thanks.
`source2 = $("#itemTemplate2").html();
template2 = Handlebars.compile(source2);
html2 = template(bookingdetails);
$('.div2').html(html2);`

Comment: could you add in jsfiddle and give the link, so that it is easy for us debug.